# How to remove blue from xamarin applications?

Tags: xamarin.forms

I'm practicing developing xamarin mobile app and when testo on my mobile phone gets a blue color on the top bar of the mobile and also as the app's default color. How to remove and change this color that is pre-defined when we create the project?

![image 1]https://scontent.fcpq5-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-9/50785265_174384576870086_2929460891814461440_n.jpg?_nc_cat=104&_nc_oc=AQkMQTbG9_i30yPV9T1SPPzac_jrsSUfExG5oKNNzD9OhmtoInI_IuNuVm55h4SE2XE&_nc_ht=scontent.fcpq5-1.fna&oh=dd90bb45569614f610755c7c4016be59&oe=5CBEE11D

![image 2]https://scontent.fcpq5-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-9/50692571_174384606870083_9113792680806055936_n.jpg?_nc_cat=106&_nc_oc=AQlqiLqP4cCcflQuo7Rpn_1gU7BWCiP0BQFqIRJeWjGc_1P1T8z53Y2z2mzleLuKM4E&_nc_ht=scontent.fcpq5-1.fna&oh=027ff4784a251c018cc475d9d1808159&oe=5CFCECE8

I tried changing the BarBackGroundColor property of my TabbedPage and it did not work. The bar has gone black but the blue color remains.

Answer (score 0):

In Android: change the color in the file located in `\Resources\values\styles.xml` and edit:

```
<item name="colorPrimaryDark">#00FF00</item>
```

To the color you desire.